# My javascript have : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of null show on my console

Tags: javascript

I want to remove my popup message modal with setTimeout but the console shows this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null

My code:

```js
function popupmodel(msg2) {
  const mymodel1 = document.createElement('div');
  const mypopbox2 = document.querySelector(".bodybg");
  mymodel1.classList = `mypopbox`;
  mymodel1.innerHTML = `
    <div class="row mt-5 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <p>${msg2}</p>
        <button id="gameClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
  `;
  mypopbox2.appendChild(mymodel1);
  const closebut1 = document.querySelector('.mypopbox');
  document.getElementById('gameClose').addEventListener('click', function() {
    closebut1.remove();
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.mypopbox').remove();
  }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: Kindly post working fiddle or codepan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Your code works already!***

```js
function popupmodel(msg2) {
  const mymodel1 = document.createElement('div');
  const mypopbox2 = document.querySelector(".bodybg");
  mymodel1.classList = `mypopbox`;
  mymodel1.innerHTML = `
    <div class="row mt-5 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <p>${msg2}</p>
        <button id="gameClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
  `;
  mypopbox2.appendChild(mymodel1);
  const closebut1 = document.querySelector('.mypopbox');
  document.getElementById('gameClose').addEventListener('click', function() {
    closebut1.remove();
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.mypopbox').remove();
  }, 3000);
};

popupmodel("hello");
```

```html
<div class="bodybg">

</div>
```

However, for the error you mentioned should be caused by the below line and it means it is not able to find anything with class "mypopbox". If you still facing the issue kindly reproduce it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and share.

```
document.querySelector('.mypopbox').remove();
```